# SQL Server Database Project is not showing unresolved object reference warning

Tags: sql-server, msbuild

I have a problem with SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio Community 2022 (Version 17.3.5).

It looks like if there is a reference to a not existing function in the select statement, where in 'from' or 'join' statement is a variable of table type or user-defined table type, MSBuild stops tracking reference to the function and compiles the project without any warning.

How to force MSBuild to check also that kind of reference?
It is quite frustrating because may produce runtime errors after deployment to the SQL server database.

I've tried with a blank SQL Server Database Project with one simple procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SimpleProcedure]
AS
declare @b table(id int)
select dbo.UDF_NotExistingFunction() someColumn
--from @b
```

In this form MSBuild says:

> Warning SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[SimpleProcedure] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[UDF_SomeNotExistingFunction].

When 'from @b' is uncommented, MSBuild compiles the project without being notified about this kind of issue.

Comment: without comment , it's being treated as a scalar UDF ; with, as a TVF

Comment: Is it matter? When I add a `table [dbo].[MyTable] (id int)` into the project and modify the procedure to: 
`CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SimpleProcedure] 
 AS
 declare @b table(id int)
 select 
    mt.Id MyTableId, 
    dbo.UDF_SomeNotExistingFunction(mt.Id) notExistingColumn 
 from dbo.MyTable mt 
--join @b b on b.id=mt.Id`
still have the same issue. As soon as table type variable is in 'from' or 'join' statement - MSBuild stops tracking reference to UDF

Comment: Maybe obvious, but check that you haven't suppressed 71502 warnings for the project.

Comment: There is no warning suppressed for that project. It would suppress the warning for the situation with the 'join' statement commented out as well. It seems to be a bug in MSBuild or the tools it uses for database compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in msbuild. On several projects I have had to re-write code in order to make msbuild work.

One suggestion is to try a #temporary table instead of a table variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in msbuild. I've reported it on MS Developer Community forum:

[Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/SQL-Server-Database-Project-is-not-showi/10184669)